# why is it 'to send somebody into pandemonium' but not 'with pandemonium'

Tags: prepositions, vocabulary

> Rio Olympics 2016: Thiago Braz Da Silva sent Brazil into pandemonium

It's from [this Web site](https://www.nzherald.co.nz/sport/rio-olympics-2016-thiago-braz-da-silva-sent-brazil-into-pandemonium/QRG4FO64HL5PH5Z62SRI6ZMOZY/) So Thiago Braz Da Silva won the gold medal, and if I'm not mistaken, people applauded him very loudly. Well, I looked up several dictionaries including *dictionary.com*, *OALD* and *Cambridge Dictionary (online)* and haven't find examplary sentences with 'with pandemonium' but 'into pandemonium' really doesn't make sense to me. Why is it 'to send sb into pandemonium' ?

Comment: Might you be thinking of "**to send** something (to someone) **with love** / *affection / thanks / best wishes / vehemence / urgency"?*  but to send sth with pandemonium would be highly unlikely as it is a condition a situation not a *feeling*.

Answer (score 2):

> Pandemonium: a situation in which there is a lot of noise and confusion because people are excited, angry, or frightened  (Cambridge)

So you can go *into pandemonium*. It means to enter *into* a state of wild uproar. But it isn't idiomatic to go *with* a state of wild uproar.

Answer (score 2):

The original meaning of Pandemonium was "[A place where all demons live; Hell](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pandemonium#Noun)", and we can still think of it as a state for something to be in, so "send somebody into Pandemonium" makes sense that way (though I think it's unlikely to be used of an individual person: in your exemple it is a country).

We could also say "cause pandemonium in/for" - but we wouldn't then use the verb "send", because that invokes the metaphor of sending somebody into somewhere.